# Show ImageView from bottom to top progressively with a duration

Tags: swift

I have an imageView and I want to show the image progressively from bottom to top with a duration of 2 seconds. Anyone of you has an idea? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Cover the image with a UIView of equal width and height, then reduce the height of the cover gradually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy way to create this effect.
Create a UIView, and bring it to the front. (Set the frame to the size of the image, and position directly over the image). Make sure to give it a color.

```
let square = UIView()
square.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100)
square.backgroundColor = .purple
view.addSubview(square)
view.bringSubviewToFront(square)
```

Then just animate the object up by setting the y value to negative.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
    square.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: -100, width: 200, height: 100)
}
```

Comment: Hey Evan! that's a good ansewer. thank you for your reply!